# php elseif not working

Tags: php, sorting

I am adding a sort function to my product search page. User can choose to sort by Price, ascending or descending and Product name, ascending or descending. The default is to sort by PRoduct ID.

First I check to see if 'sortBy' is not set, if it isn't I use the default SQL query ordering by ProductID. Second I check to see if the '$orderBy' variable coming in the GET is either 'NameA2Z' or 'NameZ2A', if it is I use a ternary operator to assign ASC or DESC accordingly.

Here is where the problem comes in, I do the same thing in the following 'else' statement, only I check to see if '$orderBy is either 'PriceH2L' or 'PriceL2H' but no matter what I pass to it in the querystring, it never gets here.

It seems like `elseif($_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameA2Z" || "NameZ2A")` always evaluates to TRUE no matter what.

```
$searchTerm = "";
$orderBy = "";
$searchSQL = "";
$searchTerm ="";
$searchTerm = $_GET["searchItem"];


if(!isset($_GET['sortOrder'])){
    $searchSQL = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE "%' . $searchTerm . '%"     ORDER BY ProductID';    
}
elseif($_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameA2Z" || "NameZ2A"){
    $orderBy = ($_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameZ2A" ? "DESC" : "ASC");
    $searchSQL = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE "%' . $searchTerm . '%" ORDER   BY ProductName '. $orderBy . ' ' ;
    }
else{
    $orderBy = ($_GET["sortOrder"] == "PriceH2L" ? "DESC" : "ASC");
    $searchSQL = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE "%' . $searchTerm . '%" ORDER     BY ProductPrice ' . $orderBy  . ' ';
    echo ' Sort from second else is: ' . $orderBy;
 }
```

Here is the HTML just in case:

```
<select id="searchSort" searchterm='<?php echo $searchTerm  ?>'  >
         <option value="husker">Sort results by</option>
        <option value="PriceH2L">Price - Lowest to highest</option>
        <option value="PriceL2H">Price - Highest to lowest</option>
        <option value="NameA2Z">Name - A to Z</option>
        <option value="NameZ2A">Name = Z to A</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't people remember what a paragraph is?

Comment: Please read about php syntax and operators presedence

Comment: `$_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameA2Z" || $_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameZ2A"` if you leave only `|| "NameZ2A"` this ever will be true

Comment: "Don't people remember what a paragraph is? " Not supposed to end sentence with a preposition.

Comment: The `elseif` is not comparing to your `NameZ2A` correctly.  That is why it is always evaluating to `true`.

Comment: Sorry, "know" what a paragraph is. My bad. Break up your sentences.

Comment: Fred.....hoist on his  own petard. Thanx ahmet. I will Fred when you stop ending sentences in prepositions.

Comment: It's not so much about grammar, it's about [readability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability). ;-) you can do a rollback if you want.

Comment: @DuckofDeath See this article: [Ending a Sentence With a Preposition](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the condition in the `elseif`:

```
$_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameA2Z" || "NameZ2A"
```

This reads: Is `$_GET["sortOrder"]` equal to `"NameA2Z"`, or is the string `"NameZ2A"` true?

The string `"NameZ2A"` will always be true. You probably want do to:

```
$_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameA2Z" || $_GET["sortOrder"] == "NameZ2A"
```